# how to correctly copy /clone a structure? and should I use a class instead?

Tags: .net

let say i have that

```
Structure myStruct
    Public myPoint As Point
    Public myBool As Boolean
End Structure
```

how to I make a copy / clone of that structure?

I fixed that issue now,
example of the code I was using:

```
    Dim myStruct(1) As myStruct 
    myStruct(0).myPoint = New Point(10, 10)
    myStruct(0).myBool = True

    Dim myCopy(1) As myStruct
    myCopy = myStruct
    myCopy(0).myBool = False
    myCopy(0).myPoint = New Point(11, 11)
```

with that, both variable was changed

I had to do

```
    myCopy = CType(myStruct.Clone, myStruct())
```

and another question, if that structure is used, let say, 10,000 times, should I created a class instead?

Comment: doesn't really matter but in this case, vb.net but I can work with a C# solution

Comment: Youre doing it wrong. Youre assigning one array of myStruct to another.

Comment: @BC, no, at least not with vb.net, it's going to use local variable for the myCopy=myStruct and it's going to use the structure itself for the declaration

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking at 12 bytes per structure, so passing it around as a struct is cheaper than creating a word-sized reference to it on heap (in other words, using a class)

If you need to access all 10,000 at once, creating an array of them will happen on the heap even if they are structs.

Copying the struct is as easy as creating declaring another struct of the same type and assigning the first to the second.

Comment: do you mean something structVar1 == structVar2 ? that doesn't make a copy

Comment: @Fredou No, structVar1 = structVar2.

Comment: @Fredou, a == b is a compare.  a = b is an assignment.  (At least in C#.)

Comment: @strager, I remembered that when I clicked Add comment, was too late to change it

Comment: without an array, var1 = var2 work well, not with an array, see my question for how i fixed it...

Comment: thanks, I just switched a class into a structure, removing a lot of code.

Comment: A little explanation of the last line: "Copying the struct is as easy as creating declaring another struct of the same type and assigning the first to the second."  i.e.  struct2 = struct1. It will work because stucts are value type and they are stored on stack, instead of reference types [e.g. class] which are stored on heap. An Array will no more be a value type, so this assignment will not work.

Comment: Yes, BiLal, good point, this answer is potentially misleading. In the question the declaration of myStruct and myCopy as arrays is what creates the requirement to use myCopy = myStruct.clone.  If it were not declared as an array [i.e. Dim myStruct as myStruct (yes this is legal, although a poor choice of variable name), Dim myCopy as myStruct, then assignment through the equals operator would suffice to create a copy, i.e. myCopy = myStruct.

Answer (score 2):

The reason that you had to use the Clone method was that you were copying the Array object, not the structure. This works for copying the structure value:

```
Dim myStructArray(0) As MyStruct
myStructArray(0).MyPoint = New Point(10, 10)
myStructArray(0).MyBool = True

Dim myCopyArray(0) As MyStruct
myCopyArray(0) = myStructArray(0) 'copy structure instead of array
myCopyArray(0).MyBool = False
myCopyArray(0).MyPoint = New Point(11, 11)
```

In this case it's of course totally pointless to copy the structure as you are replacing all the values, but the copying does work, leaving you with two separate arrays instead of two references to the same array.

A structure should generally be immutable, i.e. it's properties are read-only, which protects you from situations like this:

```
Dim myStructList(Of MyStruct) As New myStructList(Of MyStruct)()
myStructList.Add(New MyStruct())
myStructList(0).MyPoint = New Point(10, 10) 'doesn't work
```

The reason that this doesn't work is that myStructList(0) returns a copy of the structure. The MyPoint member of the copy is changed, but the copy of the structure is never written back to the list.

This is the immutable structure:

```
Structure MyStruct

   Private _myPoint As Point
   Private _myBool As Boolean

   Public Readonly Property MyPoint As Point
      Get
         Return _myPoint
      End Get
   End Property

   Public Readonly Property MyBool As Boolean
      Get
         Return _myBoolean
      End Get
   End Property

   Public Sub New(ByVal myPoint As Point, ByVal myBool As Boolean)
      _myPoint = myPoint
      _myBool = myBool
   End Sub

End Structure
```

You create a new value using the constructor:

```
Dim myStructList(Of MyStruct) As New myStructList(Of MyStruct)()
myStructList.Add(New MyStruct(New Point(10, 10), True))
```

You can still copy the whole structure value:

```
Dim myStructArray(0) As MyStruct
myStructArray(0) = New MyStruct(New Point(10, 10), True)

Dim myCopyArray(0) As MyStruct
myCopyArray(0) = myStructArray(0) 'copy structure value
```

Answer (score 1):

To make a copy of a struct, you **must declare a new instance** of it. I usually do this by implementing my own Clone() method in the struct. For example:

```
Friend Structure SomeStructure
  Dim ValueA As Integer
  Dim ValueB As Integer
  Dim Values() As Integer
  Public Function Clone() As SomeStructure
    Dim theClone As SomeStructure
    theClone.ValueA = Me.ValueA
    theClone.ValueB = Me.ValueB
    ReDim theClone.Values(Me.Values.GetUpperBound(0))
    Array.Copy(Me.Values, theClone.Values, Me.Values.Length)
    Return theClone
  End Function
End Structure
```

Answer (score 0):

Note for Visual Basic 2013:
To copy the structure using estructure2=estructure1
Will not create a copy of estructure1 into structure2; instead it will assign a reference of structure1 to structure2.
In this case accessing structure2 will give the same field values as structure1.
If any of the structure1 fields change, the values accessed using structure2 will change too, because they are pointing to the same data. In this sense is not a copy at all.